# одновременная работа с std::wcout и std::cout

Tags: c++, utf-8, вывод, кириллица

Все примеры я запускаю в такой main ф-ии:

```
// работа с локалью взята отсюда 
// https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale
int main() {
    locale::global(std::locale("") );
    wcout.imbue(std::locale());
    cout.imbue(std::locale());

    return 0;
}
```

Для начала вопрос про работу с объектами std::wcout и std::cout.

добавим только такую строку в мейн

```
wcout << L"добро1" << endl; // именно это и выведется в консоль
```

а теперь только такую

```
cout << "добро2" << endl; // именно это и выведется в консоль
```

а теперь обе:

```
wcout << L"добро1" << endl; // выведется только это, но правилньо
cout << "добро2" << endl;   // ни как не вывелось! даже перевода строки нет.
```

а теперь поменяем местами:

```
cout << "добро2" << endl; //добро2
wcout << L"добро1" << endl; //4>1@>1
```

`<<endl` на сколько я помню/знаю должен полностью очищать объект c++ потока, заставляя этот объект полностью отдавать всё своё содержимое устройству стандартного вывода.

Это так и есть (если в ф-ях делать отладку и делать '\n' вместо endl то однажды будет случай неправильной последовательности вывода) только если работаешь с одним из объектов cout или wcout.

**вопрос**. Есть ли способ одновременной работы и с тем и с другим объектом чтобы ничего не терялось и все выводилось на стандартный вывод. При этом обращение к cout и wcout могут быть вообще из разных мест проекта. Возможно ли такое?

Comment: std::cout << "добро1" << std::flush;

Comment: Нельзя одновременно разными I/O потоками пользоваться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда `wcout/cout` вызывается впервые, устанавливается определенная ориентация `stdout`(стандартный поток вывода). В случае `cout` поток становится однобайтно-ориентированным, а в случае `wcout` поток становится ориентированным на широкоформатные символы. Согласно стандарту C++ [27.4.1] и стандарту С [7.19.2] (C11 [7.21.2]), однажды установив ориентацию `stdout` нельзя вызывать функции несовместимые с установленной ориентацией.

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947949/mixing-cout-and-wcout-in-same-program)

Answer (score 3):

Как и было сказано одновременно печатать с разными форматами нельзя. Но. Можно закрыть поток и открыть. Этим редко кто занимается.

```
# include <cstdio>
# include <iostream>
int main(){
  int mode = fwide(stdout,0);
  std::cout<<"0.mode="<<mode<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"ABC"<<std::endl;
  mode = fwide(stdout,0);
  std::cout<<"1.mode="<<mode<<std::endl;
  freopen(NULL,"w",stdout);
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
  mode = fwide(stdout,0);
  std::wcout<<L"2.mode="<<mode<<std::endl;
  std::wcout<<L"Ура"<<std::endl;
  mode = fwide(stdout,0);
  std::wcout<<L"3.mode="<<mode<<std::endl;
  freopen(NULL,"w",stdout);
  mode = fwide(stdout,0);
  std::cout<<"4.mode="<<mode<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Again"<<std::endl;
  mode = fwide(stdout,0);
  std::cout<<"5.mode="<<mode<<std::endl;}
```

Результат:

```
0.mode=0
ABC
1.mode=-1
2.mode=0
Ура
3.mode=1
4.mode=0
Again
5.mode=-1
```